# Web API Multipart form data: how to read form data into a string, instead of save as file

Tags: multipartform-data, asp.net-web-api

In my controller I use code below to process multipart form data:

```
    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    if (!Directory.Exists(root))
    {
        throw new QLApplicationException("Error ...");
    }
    MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
     Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>
```

This works fine except that it only saves the form data into a file at /App_Data. What I need however, is to get the data into a string in my program so I don't have to read it out again from the file. How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` only saves any uploaded files into the file system. If you are looking to access the form values, you can do `provider.FormData` to get them.

If you are looking to access the uploaded file itself in-memory without saving it as a file on the drive, then you can use `MultipartMemoryStreamProvider` which reads all uploaded parts of the incoming request into memory. You can access each of this part by accessing the `HttpContents` property on the provider.